# Are reference resistors required for VRP and VRN when implementing an DDR2 memory controller in an Artix-7 device?

Tags: memory, xilinx, vivado, artix-series-fpga, ddr2

The generated pinout does not list any VRP or VRN pins, or anything similar.

I have specified internal impedance for the DDR2 IF pins with IO standard SSTL18_II.  On previous and other FPGAs, it is then typically required to provided some reference resistor on the FPGA, to allow calibration of internal impedance.  However, I have not been able to find this on the Artix-7 device.

I have looked through the pinout documentation for the Artix-7 35T in FGG484 package, but there is no description of VRP and VRN pins.

So, are the reference resistors not required for DDR2 on Artix-7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the Artix-7 device only have High-Range (HR) banks, which does not have Digitally-Controlled Impedance (DCI) based on external reference resistor.

It is described in document "7 Series FPGAs SelectIO Resources User Guide" section "Uncalibrated Split Termination in High-Range I/O Banks (IN_TERM)".

The termination specification "UNTUNED_SPLIT_50" applies this kind of uncalibrated internal termination.

Comment: EquipDev - Hi, Thanks for adding the [answer to your own question](/help/self-answer). As you can see in that linked article, to accept you own answer you must wait 48 hours after you asked the question. So please consider coming back in a couple of days and "[accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234)" your answer (or another answer, if a better one has been added in the meantime).  That will effectively close the topic and remove the question from the unanswered list. Thanks.